# wildfly database pools are being filled in

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly-8

I have some application running on wildfly 8.2.1 and every days database pools are being filled in

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/etenderDS" pool-name="etenderDS" use-ccm="true">
  <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">
    host
  </xa-datasource-property>
  <xa-datasource-property name="PortNumber">
    5432
  </xa-datasource-property>
  <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">
    dbname
  </xa-datasource-property>
  <driver>postgresql</driver>
  <xa-pool>
    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>2000</max-pool-size>
    <capacity>
      <decrementer class-name="org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.capacity.MinPoolSizeDecrementer"/>
    </capacity>
    <prefill>false</prefill>
    <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
    <flush-strategy>Gracefully</flush-strategy>
  </xa-pool>
  <security>
    <user-name>username</user-name>
    <password>password</password>
  </security>
  <recovery>
    <recover-plugin class-name="org.jboss.jca.core.recovery.ValidatingManagedConnectionFactoryRecoveryPlugin"/>
  </recovery>
  <validation>
    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
  </validation>
  <timeout>
    <idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>
  </timeout>
</xa-datasource>
```

**My question**: Is it normal? why wildfly required many pools? How can I reduce wildfly pools?

Comment: Is it possible that you are leaking connections? This happens when you fail to call [Connection.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close--) for connections that you acquire from the datasource that you defined above.

Comment: If you enable crm then you will get warnings if you don't close resources properly